# Sequence bounded away from $0$ and $2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Suppose I have a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_n$ and I'm told that $\{a_n\}_n$ is **bounded away** from $0$ and $2$.

(1) What does it mean exactly? My thinking is that it means $a_n\neq 0$ and $a_n \neq 2$ $\forall n$.

(2) Does it imply that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n \neq 0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n \neq 2$ (assuming that the limit exists)?

Question (2) is related to the discussion on rescaling rates at p.211 of van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics" point (iii) [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UEuQEM5RjWgC&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=rescaling+rates+van+der+vaart+this+lemma+implies+that+for+any+sequence&source=bl&ots=mnSERF7-Lu&sig=o87gqDYx0qdZRzVqyGdIuJ0T-Kc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD_Y-45-DKAhWBPg8KHQ4DBXoQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=rescaling%20rates%20van%20der%20vaart%20this%20lemma%20implies%20that%20for%20any%20sequence&f=false)
where it seems that the answer to (2) is "Yes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounded away from $b$ means that there is a nontrivial interval around $b$ such that the sequence never enters it.

In particular, if a sequence is bounded away from $b$ then it cannot converge to $b$. More generally, $b$ cannot be a limit point of the sequence.

Comment: Even more, no subsequence of it can converge to $b$.

Comment: @LeeMosher, right, I've added that. Thanks.

Comment: To be even more explicit in the first part: there exists a constant $\epsilon > 0$ such that $a_n\in[\epsilon, 2-\epsilon]$ for all $n$.

Comment: @ClementC., you mean $\notin$.

Comment: @lhf No, I don't. Why? It's bounded *away* from $0$ and $2$.

Comment: @ClementC. But it does not mean that the sequence is in the interval $[\varepsilon,2-\varepsilon]$ for some $\varepsilon>0$, does it? The sequence $a_n=3$ for each $n$ is bounded away from $0$ and $2$, isn't it?

Comment: @lhf: sorry -- I stupidly assumed the sequence was in $[0,2]$ in the first place. My bad: the correct statement is "$a_n\in(-\infty, -\epsilon]\cup[\epsilon,2-\epsilon]\cup[2+\epsilon,\infty)$ for all $n$," without that (non-justified) assumption.. So it's indeed a $\in$, but in a different interval (or, equivalently, $a_n\notin (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cup(2-\epsilon,2+\epsilon)$)

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, it means that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ does not get close to $0$ or to $2$. There exists some $\delta>0$ such that $|a_n-0|=|a_n|>\delta$ for each $n$ and there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $|a_n-2|>\varepsilon$ for each $n$. The limit cannot be $0$ or $2$ if the sequence is bounded away.